# PHP MySQL Update Statement Won't Accept Anything But Numeric Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have the following sql update statement and the variables are being sanitized prior. The information is coming from a form and the database columns are TEXT. INSERTS work flawlessly.

DB Structure:

file_title=text file_description=text id=INT

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE images
        SET file_title=$FileTitle, file_description=$FileDescription
        WHERE id=$image_id");
```

For some unknown reason I can only update using numeric values as it just won't update using any text which is frustrating.

I must just be missing something really basic. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHAR values must be quoted, but more importantly you should be using prepared statements:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE images
    SET file_title=?, file_description=?
    WHERE id=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssd', $FileTitle, $FileDescription, $image_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote text and string values:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE images
        SET file_title='$FileTitle', file_description='$FileDescription'
        WHERE id=$image_id");
```

Numeric values could be passed without quoting.

Comment: Thanks. I just put to together mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE images
   SET file_title='".$FileTitle."', file_description='".$FileDescription."'
   WHERE id='".$image_id."'"); and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

because string needs to be wrapped with single quotes. Single quotes are for string literals while backtick are for identifiers,

```
UPDATE images
SET    file_title='$FileTitle', file_description='$FileDescription'
WHERE id=$image_id
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote for text values.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE images
        SET file_title='$FileTitle', file_description='$FileDescription'
        WHERE id=$image_id");
```